# Omnet++ 5.0 fails to configure/make. Unable to launch Omnetpp IDE. Windows

Tags: omnet++

I have read about issues with previous installations of omnet 4.6. I have deleted all installations of omnet before trying this. Any help is appreciated.

What can i do to fix this and get oment 5 working :( ?

**I believe it is to do with my bin directory & make file?? But there is no documentation on how to address this that i can find. I'm very new to the world of Omnet++.**

Thanks.

Below is from the bash prompt:

```
/c/omnetpp-5.0-src-windows/omnetpp-5.0$ . setenv
bash: setenv: No such file or directory

/c/omnetpp-5.0-src-windows/omnetpp-5.0$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for clang... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... unsupported
checking for clang++... clang++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking for clang++... clang++
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether clang++ supports -std=c++11... yes
checking whether clang++ supports -fno-stack-protector... yes
checking whether clang++ supports -Wl,--no-as-needed... yes
checking whether clang++ supports -Wl,--as-needed... yes
checking for swapcontext... no
checking if shared libs need -fPIC... no
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... no
checking if --export-dynamic linker option is supported/needed... test failed
checking for flags needed to link with static libs containing simple modules...                                                      --whole-archive
configure: NOTE: Use the following syntax when linking with static libraries
configure: containing simple modules and other dynamically registered components                                                     :
configure:    clang++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive <libs> -Wl,--no-whole-archive ...
checking whether linker supports -rpath... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... configure: error: cannot find output from flex;                                                      giving up

/c/omnetpp-5.0-src-windows/omnetpp-5.0$ make
Makefile:36: Makefile.inc: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: *** OMNETPP_BIN_DIR must be correctly set.  Stop.

/c/omnetpp-5.0-src-windows/omnetpp-5.0$ omnetpp
bash: omnetpp: command not found
```

Comment: Try to temporary disable your antivirus program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your ZIP file is corrupted (or the utility you use to extract is not working correctly). The windows unzip program is known to have these issues. A virus checker can also cause these as suggested in the comment.

Comment: I used 7-zip and i've re-downloaded it twice. I will disable anti virus and let you know how it goes tomorrow. Are there any files i should check to make sure its not pointing to old version folders?

Comment: 1. Make sure that the download is intact: md5sum  for the 5.0 windows zip file should be: 0a71bfa770a772acd7e92e484c7c5fc0.

Comment: 2. The windows version, does *NOT* have a setenv file. Sourcing setenv (. setenv) is needed only on Linux/macOS. On windows, you should start the mingwenv.cmd file and run ./configure there immediately.

Comment: I'd just like to say i successfully installed 5.1. I'm not sure if its because i disabled my AV or because 5.1 is 64 bit only and not interfering with previous installations.